# Pulling or Auto Populate A Form Input Field

Tags: php

Ok i am trying to find if this is possible, i have a single page that has two login forms. But uses the same username and password. Is it possible whereas once i log into one form my username is pulled from the from that already has my username and the password is pulled from the database?

```
<form action="home.php" method="post" id="LoginForm" style="color:#FFF">
<input type="hidden" name="SessionID" value="new"></input>
Username:
<input type="text" name="AccountNo" value="" class="input" size="28"></input>
<BR /><BR />
&nbsp;&nbsp;Password:
<input type="password" name="Password" value="" class="input" size="30"></input>
<BR />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="image" src="images/input-img.gif" value="Log On" class="input-img"></input>
<BR /><br />
<a href="#" class="link" style="font-size:12px;">Register now!</a>   <a href="#" style="font-size:12px;">Forgotten your password?</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is whether it is possible, then answer is yes it is possible.

After you submit the form, you can use JavaScript to read the username from first form and populate it in the second form. To get password, you can AJAX.

Comment: <?php  
    
    $link = mysql_connect('link','name','pw')
   or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
   
   mysql_select_db("db_name") or die("Could not select database");
   
    $query_sel = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Code = '$Edit_Code'";
       $result = mysql_query($query_sel) or die(" Query failed : " . mysql_error());

   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ;
?>

Comment: <form action="" method="get">
<input type="TEXT" value="<?php echo $_GET['AccountNo']?>"name="Name" size="55" class="main" >
<input type="TEXT" value="<?php echo $_GET['Password']?>"name="Name" size="55" class="main" ></form>

Comment: yeah i am trying to figure out will this pull the username and password of my first form after i log in?

Comment: MY page has two forms, one form is used to access your account name and balance, the second form then shows, once you login again you then have access to some images

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to 1. either combine both forms into one or 2. find a way where the second form pulls the first form username and the password for that username from the database

Comment: I am trying to eliminate where a user doesn't have to login twice

Comment: I think the better option is to just have one form and handle the logic in your backend.

Comment: ok now my problem is both forms uses separate sessions...im willing to compensate $100 if i can get this single form to work